# How to test FusedLocationProviderClient in android?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

```
public class LocationRepository {

Context context;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private static final String TAG = "LocationRepository";

public LocationRepository(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Single<String> getLocationData() {
    return Single.create(e -> {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        getFusedLocationClient().requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), new LocationCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                String locationData = locationResult.getLocations().get(0).toString();
                e.onSuccess(locationData);
            }
        }, Looper.myLooper());
    });
}
```

I want to test `getLocationData()` return location or not. I tried with TestObserver but could not make it. How to test method having Looper in it?

Comment: add a toast and you can download apps like fake location ,or mock location to test them realtime.

Comment: @NehaK Can you share any example?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps

Comment: @NehaK please share complete code example.